# How can i go through xml data sorted by date and get a list of a custom class?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I’m trying to go through data stored in an xml file in an application coded with visual basic, build using wpf, running on windows 7 using .net framework 4.0
I have searched a lot, I went through a lot of posts on this forum (and others), but I’m lost. I haven't ben able to find a proper documentation. I hope that someone can give me an answer here.
This is my xml schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Changes">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="change" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element> 
    <xs:element name="change">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="engine" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="reference" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="code" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="number" type="xs:integer"/>
                <xs:element name="startdate" type="xs:date"/>
                <xs:element name="stopdate" type="xs:date"/>
                <xs:element name="location" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="carracteristic" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="tolmin" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="tolmax" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="correctiveaction" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="correctiveactiondeadline" type="xs:date"/>
                <xs:element name="duplicate" type="xs:boolean"/>
                <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="justification " type="xs:boolean"/>
                <xs:element name="status" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="nature" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="ongoingactions" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="actor" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="timelimit" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="justif" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="newstatus" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="linktomap" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

What I want to do is to get a list of `change` for a specific `reference` for which the current date is comprised between the `startdate` and the `stopdate`.

So far I have managed to get a list of `change` for my ref.

```
Function applicableChanges(ByVal ref As String, ByVal changesfilepath As String) As List(Of change)

    Dim xmlchange As New XmlDocument

    xmlchange.Load(changesfilepath)
    Dim changeList As XmlNodeList
    changeList = root.SelectNodes("change[reference='" & ref & "']")
End function
```

But I can't get further.

1 How can I get only changes that are relevant as of today (`reference=ref and Now()>startdate and Now()<stopdate`)?

My second problem is then how to go through the extracted data.
`changeList` is a XmlNodeList. How can I get attributes values for each change in this list (like `number`, `code`,...).

There must be a way to loop through this XmlNodeList, but I can't find it.

Or what I thought might be a good idea, was to create a vb class `change` that contain the same attributes as my xml elements and somehow convert my XmlNodeList in a `List(Of change). I think this might be deserialization if I understand it correctly.

2 What is the best way to navigate through the extracted data, and how?

Thanks’ in advance for any help.

Comment: I'd suggest using [XSD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx) to generate a class, deserialize the data, and use Linq to select and order the objects you want from the resulting List of `change`.

Answer (score 0):

Mr.Gadget is referring to the Xsd.exe tool that will convert your schema to a set of classes.  You can then deserialize your XML into this Object hierarchy and make whatever use you need of the data.

On my current machine it can be found at :C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools\x64

You should be able to find it on yours.

This link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx
will help you understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. I didn't take time to explore Xsd I built my serializable class on my own. I keep that in my mind for latter if i have time.

However i used deserialization and Linq (i didn't know about it). It works great.
Linq is really powerfull.

Thanks